# If $x^2+px-q=0$ and $x^2+px+q=0$ have integer roots for real $p$ and $q$, then $p^2=a^2+b^2$ for some integers $a$ and $b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, pythagorean-triples

> Two equations $x^2+px-q=0$ and $x^2+px+q=0$ have integer roots, where $p$ and $q$ are real numbers. Prove that for some integers $a$ and $b$, $p^2 = a^2 + b^2$. In other words, have $\{a,b,p\}$ be a Pythagorean triple.

I used the quadratic equation and found that $p^2-4q$ and $p^2+4q$ are both perfect squares, and thus $2p^2 = m^2+k^2$, but I'm stuck and not sure how to continue.

Comment: This is trivially true since $p^2 = p^2 + 0^2$ and $0$ is an integer. Also, if $q=0$ then any integer $p$ works, including those that are not a pythagorean hypotenuse. Maybe there are additional conditions missing?

Answer (score 6):

We observe that,

$$
\begin{align}&\begin{cases}p^2+4q=m^2,\thinspace m\in\mathbb Z_{>0}\\ p^2-4q=n^2,\thinspace n\in\mathbb Z_{>0}\end{cases}\\\\
\implies &2p^2=m^2+n^2,\thinspace {\color{#c00}{p\in\mathbb Z_{>0}}}\tag {*}\end{align}
$$

This implies that, $m$ and $n$ have the same parities. This means, there exist $(a,b)\in\mathbb Z^2$ such that,

$$
\begin{align}&\begin{cases}m=a+b\\
n=a-b\end{cases}\implies \begin{cases}a=\frac {m+n}{2}\\ b=\frac {m-n}{2}\end{cases}\end{align}
$$

holds .

This leads to :

$$
\begin{align}&2p^2=2(a^2+b^2)\\
\implies &p^2=a^2+b^2\end{align}
$$

where $a=\frac {m+n}{2}$ and $b=\frac {|m-n|}{2}\thinspace .$

---

${(^*)}\thinspace\thinspace$We assume that $\thinspace p\in\mathbb Z^{+}$, since $(a,b,p)$ is a [Pythagorean triple](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple) .

Comment: Just to nitpick on the last line, you can't assume $p \in \mathbb Z^+$ based on the conclusion you want to prove. You know that $p \in \mathbb Z$ because the roots are integers, but $p$ doesn't have to be positive. For example $p=-5,q=6$ satisfies the conditions, and your proof works to show that $(-5)^2 = 3^2+4^2$ even though $(3,4,-5)$ would not be usually called a pythagorean triplet.

Comment: @dxiv Thank you very much for reviewing the answer .